# How to get data from a URL by JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I am given a URL from World Bank and I was told to get data from it.  I checked the JSON api pages but did not understand where to start.  It is an Android app that I am practicing and I have to choose some indicators and get data by that URL.  I need to know where to start and some basic advice about using JSON. So as a programmer, if you are given a url to get data from, how would you start ?

```
String myDataString = "URL STRING"; 
    String dataString = new String();
```

Answer (score 4):

I did a android project recently fetching data from a json file on a remote server. I used something like this.

```
public void getData(String URL) {
    AsyncTask<String,String,String> getTask = new AsyncTask<String,String,String>(){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String response = "";
            try{
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
                        url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader
                reader = new
                BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    response += line + "\n";
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
            }
            return response;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    };
    getTask.execute(URL);
}
```

So you wanna do an AsyncTask to avoid the activity from crashing when it is waiting for response. It opens a urlConnection, initiates a bufferedReader and keeps reading when more lines are to be found. When it is done, it prints the result to console.

I found that this way seemed the most common when fetching data from JSON to an android app. How you manipulate the data is up to you, some use strings some use JSON objects..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to start with a tutorial on how to parse a remote JSON : [Android JSON Parsing from URL – Example](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-json-parsing-url-example.html)